# How to properly resize a ListBox while scrolling?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `ListBox` containing many items (in a virtualized panel). I am using a fixed width based on an estimate of the maximum width of the elements within it (getting the exact maximum would take too long as there are often too many items).

If my initial estimate was wrong, though, I would like the list box to grow wider to accommodate any wider items as they scroll into view.

So far, I am able to correctly detect when the list box scrolls and measure the currently visible items. I can even successfully change the width of the list box to match the widest of of these items (if larger than the current width, that is).

However, there remains one bug: If the user is scrolling by holding down on the scrollbar thumb and dragging, then if the width changes too much (more than ~100px?), the mouse cursor is no longer in the "buffer zone" of the scrollbar (which has moved) and the listbox [snaps back to the previous scroll offset](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/55623/why-do-scrollbars-revert-to-original-scroll-distance-when-mouse-is-dragged-sidew) (unless the user manually moves the cursor back over the moved scrollbar without releasing the mouse button).

So, my question is this: Is there any way to change the size of this scroll-slew buffer zone? Or disable it completely temporarily? I can't even figure out the official name of this scrolling "feature", making related searches difficult. Is it even possible to change the width of the list box while scrolling without potentially triggering this bug?

**Update:**
I found the [constant in the .NET source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/Primitives/ScrollBar.cs,756). It's called `MaxPerpendicularDelta`. It doesn't seem like there's a way to change it or the way it's used :-(

**Another update:** Alright, I've resigned myself to the fact that there's no real way to do this. And I found another corner case, where the user is scrolling by holding down the cursor in the scrollbar gutter (above or below the thumb) -- in that case, if the scrollbar moves from under the cursor, the scrolling stops. I'll simply refrain from resizing the list box while the mouse cursor is down...

Comment: Sounds like a `BeginUpdate EndUpdate` issue here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.beginupdate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I think a resizable form (that the user can manually resize) is much better (and much less confusing) than trying to resize the listbox on the fly. As the form is resized, the listbox can adapt its size to the form. If some items are still too long, you can either provide tooltips or let the user select an item and then display it in a text area.

Comment: @DJKRAZE: How so? The items are already all added to the listbox.

Comment: Keep in mind that if you have long items, the screen width may be less than the item length, in which case the self-resizing listbox defeats itself.

Comment: @Cameron I think he meant that you should precalculate the correct width as you add the items, not during scrolling. Not sure how to do that with a virtual listbox, though - items are added on the fly.

Comment: @xxbbcc: You're probably right with regards to a user-resizable list. The list is not embedded in a form, however, but rather sits on top of a text editor (completion). There's already tooltips (which do mitigate the issue, I suppose), and there's a maximum listbox width based on a percentage of the screen width.  I can measure *all* the items in advance, yes, but it simply takes too long when there's thousands of them. I'd still like to know if it's possible to change the width while the user is scrolling without danger of the view jumping.

Comment: or you can look at trying the following for example `listBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(245, 200);` I recall seeing the same issue before on `SO` in regards to Virtual ListBox and `BeginUpdate EndUpdate` was a suggested fix.. I could be mistaken

Comment: @Cameron Some programs use owner-drawn windows for this purpose where the 'listbox' is really a dialog window with a resizing corner grip. That way you control the rendering / resizing of your 'listbox'. It's probably better (and, again, less confusing) than a listbox that keeps resizing itself from under the mouse.

Comment: @DJKRAZE: Hang on, `BeginUpdate`/`EndUpdate` is for winforms :D

Comment: `Cameron` you're correct.. my bad.. here is something you could try as well here is a `SO` link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769396/beginupdate-equivalent-in-wpf

Comment: What I have found is the ListBox and ListView will make a call to Gethashcode() when it is getting ready to paint the control.  Override Gethashcode() and deal with it there.  As whacked out as this sounds give it a try.